# Valid snakes on a plane

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

Inspired by [one of Vi Hart's videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gx5D09s5X6U) (which are a treasure trove full of potential challenge ideas)

A snake is made up of segments of same length and the connection between each segment can be straight or make a 90° turn.
We can encode such a snake (up to a rotation, which depends on the initial direction) by writing down a *slither*, the direction of turns (Straight/Left/Right) it takes. This one, starting in the top left and pointing to the right

```
-+    +--+    SR    RSSR
 |  +-+  |     S  RSL  S
 +--+  --+     LSSL  SSR
```

Would be represented by the slither `SRSLSSLRLRSSRSRSS`

And of course a planar snake cannot intersect itself (like in `SSSSLLLSS`), that would result in a horrible pixelated Game Over.

Your task is to determine whether a slither is valid or not (results in at least one self-intersection)

**Input**
A string made from letters `SLR` with `2 < length < 10000`
**Output**
Something Truthy if it is a valid slither and something Falsey if its not.

**Test cases**

```
__Valid__
SSLSLSRSRSSRSSSLLSSSRRLRSLRLLSSS
SRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLSSLLRSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRR (A hilbert curve)
RLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLSSLLRSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLSSLLRSRRLLRR
SRRSRSRSSRSSRSSSRSSSRSSSSRSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSS (Spiral)
SSSSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSSLSSSSSLSSSSSSLSSSLLRRLLRRLLSLSSSRRSSSSRSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSSS (bigger, squigglier spiral)
LRSLLRLSRSLLSRLSLRSLSSSLRRSSLSRRLRSRLRLSLRLLRLRSSLSLRLRSRSSSSSLSRRLSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRRLLSSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSLSLSLL

__Invalid__
SRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLLLRSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRR
SRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLSRSSSRSSSSSSSRSRSSSSSSSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRR
SRRSRSRSSRSSRSSSRSSSRSSSSSSSSSSRSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSS
SSSSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSSLSSSSSLSSSSSSLSSSLLRRLRLRRLLSLSSSRRSSSSRSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSSS
LRSLLRLSRSLLSRLSLRSLSSSLRRSSLSRRLRSRLRLSLRLLRLRSSLSLRLRSRSSSSSLSRRLSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRRLLSSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSLSLSLLSLRLSLRSLRSLRSLSLSLRSRLSLRSLRLSRSLLLRLRLRRRRSLSLSSLLSLSLSLSSLLSLSLLRLRSLLRSRLSLSSLLLLSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLLRRLRLRLLRLRLRLRLRLSSSSLSLRLLRLSLSSLSLSLSLSLRLLRLSLLLSRSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLRLLRLRLSLSRSRSSSLSRLRLRLRSLSLSLSRLLSRLSLSLSLSLSSLSLSLLSLSRLLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLSLSRLRLSLLRRLSLLSLSLSLSLSLLSLSLSLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRRLRSLSLSLSLSLSLSLSSLSSSSSLSLSSSLSLSLSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
```

You can [draw the slithers here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/slither/822941639) (R and L are flipped, but it doesnt affect validity)

Comment: Does input have to be done in the program or can it be read from a file?

Comment: Should SRRR be True or False? It connects but doesn't intersect itself.

Comment: touching snakes challenge NSFW?

Comment: if you draw `SRRR` on a graph paper with one square per segment then it would overlap and is therefore invalid, simply `RRR` however, would occupy exactly a 2x2 square without overlaps (just like in the classic game)

Comment: [Similar but not a duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45059/the-number-of-reachable-snake-orientations) (due to different objective and different construction rules).

Comment: +1 for [Vi Hart](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOGeU-1Fig3rrDjhm9Zs_wg) :)

Comment: "if you draw SRRR on a graph paper with one square per segment then it would overlap and is therefore invalid"  This doesn't make sense to me.  Based on the description, the turns are directional changes,  not positional ones.  So SRR would result in a single segment, which should be valid.

Comment: I gotta say it took me an embarrassingly long time to figure out the pun you were making with "snakes on a _plane_"

Answer (score 20):

## Pyth, <strike>22</strike> 20 bytes

```
ql{m+=Z*=T^.j)hCdzlz
```

[Try it yourself](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ql%7Bm%2B%3DZ*%3DT%5E.j)hCdzlz&input=SSLSLSRSRSSRSSSLLSSSRRLRSLRLLSSS&debug=0) or run the [testsuite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Lql%7Bm%2B%3DZ*%3DT%5E.j)hCdblb%0Ay%22SSLSLSRSRSSRSSSLLSSSRRLRSLRLLSSS%22%0Ay%22SRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLSSLLRSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRR%22%0Ay%22RLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLSSLLRSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLSSLLRSRRLLRR%22%0Ay%22SRRSRSRSSRSSRSSSRSSSRSSSSRSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSS%22%0Ay%22SSSSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSSLSSSSSLSSSSSSLSSSLLRRLLRRLLSLSSSRRSSSSRSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSSS%22%0Ay%22LRSLLRLSRSLLSRLSLRSLSSSLRRSSLSRRLRSRLRLSLRLLRLRSSLSLRLRSRSSSSSLSRRLSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRRLLSSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSLSLSLL%22%0Ay%22SRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLLLRSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRR%22%0Ay%22SRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLSRSSSRSSSSSSSRSRSSSSSSSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRR%22%0Ay%22SRRSRSRSSRSSRSSSRSSSRSSSSSSSSSSRSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSS%22%0Ay%22SSSSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSSLSSSSSLSSSSSSLSSSLLRRLRLRRLLSLSSSRRSSSSRSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSSS%22%0Ay%22LRSLLRLSRSLLSRLSLRSLSSSLRRSSLSRRLRSRLRLSLRLLRLRSSLSLRLRSRSSSSSLSRRLSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRRLLSSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSLSLSLLSLRLSLRSLRSLRSLSLSLRSRLSLRSLRLSRSLLLRLRLRRRRSLSLSSLLSLSLSLSSLLSLSLLRLRSLLRSRLSLSSLLLLSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLLRRLRLRLLRLRLRLRLRLSSSSLSLRLLRLSLSSLSLSLSLSLRLLRLSLLLSRSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLRLLRLRLSLSRSRSSSLSRLRLRLRSLSLSLSRLLSRLSLSLSLSLSSLSLSLLSLSRLLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLSLSRLRLSLLRRLSLLSLSLSLSLSLLSLSLSLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRRLRSLSLSLSLSLSLSLSSLSSSSSLSLSSSLSLSLSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS%22&debug=0).

Note the ASCII values of SRL, respectively 83, 76, 82. I abuse the fact that:

> *i <sup>83 + 1</sup>* = 1
>   *i <sup>76 + 1</sup>* = *i*
>   *i <sup>82 + 1</sup>* = *-i*

From here I just keep a variable for the current position and current direction. For every character I multiply the current direction with the above complex number, then add it to the current position.

At the end I check if all the visited positions are unique.

Comment: SRRR = true????

Comment: @Ewan On closer inspection - I'm not sure if that should be false or not. The head and tail connect, but do not intersect.

Comment: what about SRRRS?

Comment: @Ewan Same story - connection but no intersection. The question isn't clear what should be returned for these.

Comment: hmm I can see why SRRR is true but surely SRRRS is def false? both Ss are at the same x,y coord?

Comment: @Ewan They touch but do not intersect.

Comment: how do you define intersection? line 1 : SR line 2 RR : last S would be placed on same square as first S = interesection?

Comment: @Ewan Intersection is when two lines cross, not when they touch. See this: http://i.imgur.com/GXi4XMr.png

Comment: how would you draw SRRR?

Comment: @Ewan As a square.

Comment: Yes, i see where you are coming from now.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, 30 bytes

```
q{iF%U+:U[XWe4W1e4]=T+:T}%__&=
```

Explanation to follow soon.

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7BiF%25U%2B%3AU%5BXWe4W1e4%5D%3DT%2B%3AT%7D%25__%26%3D&input=SRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLSSLLRSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRR) or [run the whole suite](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=11%7B0%3AU%3AT%3Bl_%7BiF%25U%2B%3AU%5BXWe4W1e4%5D%3DT%2B%3AT%7D%25__%26%3D%22%20-%3E%20%22%5CN%7D*&input=SSLSLSRSRSSRSSSLLSSSRRLRSLRLLSSS%0ASRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLSSLLRSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRR%0ARLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLSSLLRSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLSSLLRSRRLLRR%0ASRRSRSRSSRSSRSSSRSSSRSSSSRSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSS%0ASSSSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSSLSSSSSLSSSSSSLSSSLLRRLLRRLLSLSSSRRSSSSRSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSSS%0ALRSLLRLSRSLLSRLSLRSLSSSLRRSSLSRRLRSRLRLSLRLLRLRSSLSLRLRSRSSSSSLSRRLSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRRLLSSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSLSLSLL%0ASRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLLLRSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRR%0ASRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLSRSSSRSSSSSSSRSRSSSSSSSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRR%0ASRRSRSRSSRSSRSSSRSSSRSSSSSSSSSSRSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSS%0ASSSSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSSLSSSSSLSSSSSSLSSSLLRRLRLRRLLSLSSSRRSSSSRSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSSS%0ALRSLLRLSRSLLSRLSLRSLSSSLRRSSLSRRLRSRLRLSLRLLRLRSSLSLRLRSRSSSSSLSRRLSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRRLLSSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSLSLSLLSLRLSLRSLRSLRSLSLSLRSRLSLRSLRLSRSLLLRLRLRRRRSLSLSSLLSLSLSLSSLLSLSLLRLRSLLRSRLSLSSLLLLSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLLRRLRLRLLRLRLRLRLRLSSSSLSLRLLRLSLSSLSLSLSLSLRLLRLSLLLSRSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLRLLRLRLSLSRSRSSSLSRLRLRLRSLSLSLSRLLSRLSLSLSLSLSSLSLSLLSLSRLLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLSLSRLRLSLLRRLSLLSLSLSLSLSLLSLSLSLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRRLRSLSLSLSLSLSLSLSSLSSSSSLSLSSSLSLSLSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS).

Comment: Damn, that was fast. I didnt even think of an algorithm to solve it myself yet.

Comment: SRRRS = true???

Comment: @Ewan umm, are we assuming that 0 is initially filled up and counts ?

Comment: I guess I am interpreting it like a game of snake, where moves take up blocks of space. and some of you guys are interpreting it as a zero width line

Comment: @Ewan My question is a bit different though. When we have a single move, say `S`, does it mean that the snake has already occupied both (0,0) and (1,0) ?

Comment: If you are using lines then can you 'occupy' any coord?

Comment: As i said, my question is not in the terms of line vs block. So lets assume, for sake of my question, these are all blocks.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 84 <s>89</s>

Run snippet in Firefox to test.

Some notes:

- the snake moves inside the f array. Unvisited cells have value `undefined`. On first visit, the tilde operator change it to -1 that is a truthy. Eventually, on a second visit the value change to 0 that is falsy and the `every` loop terminates returning false.
- in JS, array elements with non canonic indices (not numeric or negative) are somehow 'hidden', but they do exist. Here I use negative indices with no problem.

```js
F=s=>[...s].every(c=>f[p+=[1,1e5,-1,-1e5][d=d+{R:1,L:3,S:0}[c]&3]]=~f[p],d=p=0,f=[])

//TEST
$('#S').on('keyup mouseup change', Draw);

function Draw(){
  var s = S.value.toUpperCase();
  if (!s) {
    C.width = C.height = 0;
    return
  }
  C.width = 600;
  C.height = 400;
  
  var ctx = C.getContext("2d");  
  var px, py, int=0;
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#008';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.translate(300,200);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  
  [...s].forEach(c=>{
    (f[p+=[1,1e4,-1,-1e4][d=d+{R:1,L:3,S:0}[c]&3]]=~f[p])
    ? 1 
    : (++int)
    if (int==1) ctx.stroke(), ctx.strokeStyle = '#800', ctx.beginPath(), ctx.moveTo(10*px,10*py);
    
    py = (p / 1e4 | 0) - 5e3;
    px = (p % 1e4) -5e3
    ctx.lineTo(10*px, 10*py);
  }, d=0,p=50005000,f=[]);
  ctx.stroke();
  
}

valid=["SSLSLSRSRSSRSSSLLSSSRRLRSLRLLSSS",
"SRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLSSLLRSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRR",
"RLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLSSLLRSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLSSLLRSRRLLRR",
"SRRSRSRSSRSSRSSSRSSSRSSSSRSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSS",
"SSSSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSSLSSSSSLSSSSSSLSSSLLRRLLRRLLSLSSSRRSSSSRSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSSS",
"LRSLLRLSRSLLSRLSLRSLSSSLRRSSLSRRLRSRLRLSLRLLRLRSSLSLRLRSRSSSSSLSRRLSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRRLLSSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSLSLSLL"];
invalid=["SRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLRRSRLLLLRSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRR",
"SRRLSLLRRLLSLRRSRLLRSRRLLSRSSSRSSSSSSSRSRSSSSSSSRRLLRRSRLLRSRRLSLLRRLLSLRR",
"SRRSRSRSSRSSRSSSRSSSRSSSSSSSSSSRSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSS",
"SSSSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSLSSSSSSSSLSSSSSLSSSSSSLSSSLLRRLRLRRLLSLSSSRRSSSSRSSSRSSSSSSRSSSSSRSSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSRSSSSSSSSS",
"LRSLLRLSRSLLSRLSLRSLSSSLRRSSLSRRLRSRLRLSLRLLRLRSSLSLRLRSRSSSSSLSRRLSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRRLLSSLSSSRRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLSLSSSLSLSLLSLRLSLRSLRSLRSLSLSLRSRLSLRSLRLSRSLLLRLRLRRRRSLSLSSLLSLSLSLSSLLSLSLLRLRSLLRSRLSLSSLLLLSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLLRRLRLRLLRLRLRLRLRLSSSSLSLRLLRLSLSSLSLSLSLSLRLLRLSLLLSRSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSRLRLRLLRLRLSLSRSRSSSLSRLRLRLRSLSLSLSRLLSRLSLSLSLSLSSLSLSLLSLSRLLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLSLSRLRLSLLRRLSLLSLSLSLSLSLLSLSLSLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRRLRSLSLSLSLSLSLSLSSLSSSSSLSLSSSLSLSLSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS"];

V.innerHTML=valid.map(s=>F(s)+' '+s).join('\n')
I.innerHTML=invalid.map(s=>F(s)+' '+s).join('\n')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type to check and draw <input id=S>
(better full page)<br>
<canvas id=C width=1 height=1 ></canvas><br>
Valid<pre id=V></pre>
Invalid<pre id=I></pre>
```

Answer (score 6):

## TI-BASIC, <strike>49 56 53</strike> 51 bytes

```
abs(e^(i)-cumSum(i^cumSum(seq(inString("SL",sub(Ans,X,1))-1,X,1,length(Ans→X
SortA(∟X
min(ΔList(∟X
```

Similar to orlp's method, this creates a list of all points in the complex plane visited by the snake, starting at the origin. If the list has no duplicate elements, the code returns some positive value. Note that on a string of more than 999 elements, the calculator will be unable to generate a sufficiently long list, and will error.

EDIT: Saved two bytes at the cost of ugliness as no two lattice points on the complex plane can be the same distance away from e^i.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 87 <s>89</s>

```rb
F=->s{d=[1,w=1e4,-1,-w]
v=[w]+s.chars.map{|c|w+=d.rotate!(c<?R?-1:c>?R?0:1)[0]}
v==v&v}
```

Online test: http://ideone.com/pepeW2

Ungolfed version:

```rb
F = -> input {
  # Coordinates are expressed using one number,
  # that is computed using the formula `y + x*max_x`.
  # Assume max horizontal field width (max_x) to be 10000,
  # since that's the max length of the input.
  position = max_x = 1e4

  # These are possible directions to move to (coordinate deltas).
  # The current direction is always the first in the array.
  directions = [1,max_x,-1,-max_x]

  visited = [position]

  visited += input.chars.map{|c|
    # adjust current direction...
    directions.rotate! case c
    when ?L
      -1
    when ?R
      1
    when ?S
      0
    end

    # ...and move there
    position += directions[0]
  }

  # Return `true` if `visited` only contains distinct elements, `false` otherwise
  visited == visited & visited
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Golfscript 48 <s>49 50</s>

```csharp
[10.4?:z-10z~)]z*z@{'R L S'?@>(@+.`n}%n/@;\;..&=
```

Expects the string to exist on the stack and returns either `0` or `1`.

You can try it online with tests for [valid](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ewoKWzEwLjQ%2FOnotMTB6fildeip6QHsnUiBMIFMnP0A%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%3D) and [invalid](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ewoKWzEwLjQ%2FOnotMTB6fildeip6QHsnUiBMIFMnP0A%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%3D%3D) snakes.

This is basically the same idea as in [my Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49729/3527). Just the direction array is dealt with differently, because AFAIK Golfscript does not have an arary rotate function. In this case, I build a sufficiently large directions array, by multiplying it 10000 times and then trimming from its start 0, 1, or 3 elements, depending on the current command (S, R, or L). The current "direction" to move to is always the first item in the array.

Here it is with comments:

```csharp
# Build the direction array and set current position
[1 10000:z-1z~)]z*z

@{
  # For each character in the input:

  # set current direction by cutting 0, 1 or 3 elements 
  # from the beginning of the directions array
  'SR L'?
  @>

  # move to current direction
  .0=@+.

  # format as number and addd newline
  `n
}%

# split by newlines
n/

# cleanup
@;\;

# return 1 if array contains distinct elements, 0 otherwise
..&=
```

#### Edit:

Saved 1 char by modifying how the "directions" array is consumed.

#### Edit:

saved 1 char by moving increments of 10 instead of 1 to make use of the `?` (power) syntax.